# Ruby on Rails: undefined method 'before_save'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to combine several variables (integer answers for a multiple choice quiz) into one string that shows the results (e.g. "614-131").

I have the following in my **QuizBsController**:

```
class QuizBsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in
  before_save :set_bscode

  def set_bscode
    self.bscode = "#{bs01}#{bs02}#{bs03}-#{bs04}#{bs05}#{bs06}"
  end

  def show
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.new
  end

  def create
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.new

    @quiz_bs.bs01 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs01]
    @quiz_bs.bs02 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs02]
    @quiz_bs.bs03 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs03]
    @quiz_bs.bs04 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs04]
    @quiz_bs.bs05 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs05]
    @quiz_bs.bs06 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs06]

    @quiz_bs.user = current_user

    if @quiz_bs.save
      flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  def update
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:quiz_bs])

    @quiz_bs.assign_attributes(quiz_bs_params)

    if @quiz_bs.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  private
  def quiz_bs_params
    params.require(:quiz_bs).permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
  end

end
```

The string should eventually be displayed in the `show.html.erb` page of the users module:

```
  <h4>Body Structure</h4>
  <h3><%= @user.bscode %></h3>
```

I am getting an Action Controller error stating `undefined method 'before_save' for QuizBsController:Class`.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

`bscode` is an addition (from a later migration) to the 'QuizBs' table:

```
class AddBscodeToQuizBs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :quiz_bs, :bscode, :string
  end
end
```

`QuizBs` is set to `belongs_to :user` and a user `has_one :quiz_bs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`before_save` is to be used in your model.

It is an ActiveRecord Callback, which is triggered when you save your model object.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

You should be using the following code in you Model

```
before_save :set_bscode

def set_bscode
  self.bscode = "#{self.bs01}#{self.bs02}#{self.bs03}-#{self.bs04}#{self.bs05}#{self.bs06}"
end
```

Comment: see [controller 's filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Comment: I moved `before_save :set_bscode` and `def set_bscode` into the model (eliminating the error), but then `<h3><%= @user.bscode %></h3>` gets a no method error in `users#show`...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting a `NoMethodError` in `Users#show` saying `undefined method 'bscode'`

Comment: which table does `bscode` belong to? and what is the association between `User` and `QuizBs`

Comment: I'm asking this because according to you code, it seems `bscode` is an attribute of the `QuizBs` model. Whereas in your view you are calling it on a `User` object

Comment: I edited the original post with additional information.

Comment: so shouldn't you be using `@user.quiz_bs.bscode` in your view

Comment: That got rid of all the error messages (thank you!), but it still doesn't actually display the string on the `show.html.erb` page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110438/discussion-between-alfie-and-liz).